# How do I stop suggested videos on YouTube coming from my Grandma?

Tags: youtube, notifications

So I don't remember exactly what I did, either I checked my email on Gmail or logged into YouTube on my Grandma's computer, and now I keep receiving recommended videos based on videos I obviously would not watch.

I'm guessing a cookie stayed there and it seems like I'll never be free from her watch history.

How do could I remotely log out from her computer? (I have no access to it).

Comment: One way to log out of all other sessions is to change your password.

Comment: Or maybe just learn to love to those videos. No-one is getting younger, you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still haunted by unwanted video feed, you can remotely log out from anywhere and at any time you wish, just by logging in into your Gmail account and selecting **Last account activity - Details** at the bottom right of your screen and then pressing **<kbd>Sign out of all other web sessions</kbd>** button.

However, this will not solve your problem, because recommended videos are not based on local cookies, but on your history of "Watched" videos. to resolve your issue you just need to login into your YouTube account and delete from your history all videos that you never dared to watch. this will shift your YouTube analysis profile and YouTube AI will auto-correct suggestion feed for you in a few days.